# How helpful flags are considered as disputed

Tags: discussion, flagging

I have started raising helpful flags, I am a bit ignorant about it.

Under which situations flags are considered as disputed, and also is it appropriate to raise a helpful flag to one of the answer of your own question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My general rule of thumb on flagging is this:
Raise a flag if:

- There is something that needs done to the question or answer that you do not have ability yet to do yourself.
- You think there is something suspicious going on
- Rudeness or bickering in the comments

Don't flag for:

- Wrong answers, down vote instead
- Low quality answers, down vote instead, or try to see if simple edits to the question or answer make it better, for instance copying relevant pieces of information from a linked article that the author might be referring to

Comment: Great answer Eric! I was thinking the same, but you beat me to it! It's nice to see that we follow the same set of rules.

Comment: What for Link only answers? Should we raise Low Quality for link only answers?

Comment: Yes, those should be flagged. They need fixed by the author.